# Remove decimal points and commas using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
st='19.000\n20,000'
```

i want to remove the commas and points **ONLY FOR NUMBERS**. I am using the following code

```
re.sub(r'[^\d\.]','',st)
```

The result is:

> '19.00020000'

I am newbie in regex. How do I preserve the new line and remove the dot Can anyone help?

Comment: `re.sub(r'[,\.]', '', st)`

Comment: Thanks but wouldn't that replace all dots and commas?

Comment: That's what you asked for.

Comment: Sorry about that I edited the description

Comment: Please post some example input/output that shows your problem. If your string contains some dots and commas outside of numbers that are not supposed to be removed, your examples should show that.

Comment: I would just use `.translate()` instead of regex though...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`^\d` matches everything that is not a digit.

Instead, you should use `(?<=\d)[,\.]`.

`(?<=\d)` ensures that there are digits before the comma or the point.

```
import re

st = '19.000\n20,000\na.a,a'

print(re.sub(r'(?<=\d)[,\.]','',st))
>> 19000
   20000
   a.a,a
```

Answer (score 3):

`[^\d\.]`, since it starts with a `^`, matches everything that *isn't* a digit (`\d`) or point (`\.`).  If you want to remove commas and points, you want to match `,` or `\.`, which can be written `[,\.]` or `[\.,]`.  In `re.sub`, that's written `r'[,\.]`.  You replace those with the empty string (`''`) and everything else should be left as is.

**Edit** Per the change to your question, to remove commas and points between digits, one way is to use

```
re.sub(r'(?<=\d)[,\.](?=\d)','',st)
```

which will match commas or points preceded by a digit (`(?<=\d)`) and followed by a digit (`(?=\d)`).  These are called ["lookbehind" and "lookahead" assertions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).